# string ToUpper() function with ToString()

Tags: c#, string

I have used a string in C# where i am using C# in Visual studio 2008. I wanted to convert it to uppercase.

```
string lowerString = txtCheck.Text;
string upperString = lowerString.ToUpper();
```

Normally this is how i should have used, But the thing is i didn't get any error when i used it like this

```
string upperString = lowerString.ToUpper().Tostring();
```

Now i am confused that **ToUpper()** is also a function, then how can i use the second syntax where i again use **ToUpper().Tostring();** . I mean It would mean **Function1().Function2()**.

Comment: Chaining functions together like that is perfectly valid. You could also have done "txtCheck.Text.ToUpper();" for instance. Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you're calling `ToString` on the object returned by `ToUpper`.  This is pointless, but it's not a compilation error.  If you did:

```
lowerString.ToUpper.ToString();
```

that will indeed give you an error, since you can't call a method (ToString) on a method group.

Answer (score 6):

ToUpper() is a function that takes a string and returns another string, so you're OK just doing:

```
string upperString = txtCheck.Text.ToUpper();
```

No need to call ToString() at all.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as:

```
string upperString = (lowerString   .ToUpper())   .ToString();
```

In other words, the thing that get returned from `lowerString.ToUpper()` is having `ToString()` applied to it. That's redundant since it's *already* a string but it's by no means an error.

It's no different to some other languages where the equivalent would be:

```
upperString = toString (toUpper (lowerString));
```

In fact you can do all sorts of weird things like:

```
string upper = lower.ToUpper().ToLower().ToUpper().ToString().ToString();
```

although that monstrosity should never get past a code review :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you need to have .tostring.toupper or is .toupper enough to convert it to string and upper case as well. For example if it where an object. Wondering if there is any performance impact also.

Comment: @Peter, every object has a `ToString()` because it inherits from `Object` (which has it). Not every object has a `ToUpper()`. And, while you *can* use the `implicit` operator in your classes to implicitly convert to a string, I don't believe that's a feature of the `Object` class. So my understanding is that you still need `arbitraryObject.ToString().ToUpper()`. Introducing an extension method may work but you're still doing the conversion, just hiding it away in the extension code. And you probably *don't* want to extend `Object` since its impact would be huge.

Comment: In any case, I'm unsure what effect adding `ToUpper()` to `Object` would have when one of its child-classes (`String`) already has the member function. It may work but I'd be loathe to trust it :-)